# How to configure virtual host with apache2 and Node.js so it takes port number into account

Tags: node.js, apache, ubuntu

I am using my Ubuntu server to host web sites (Apache2) and Node Applications (Node.js) and I have some troubles configuring /etc/hosts when it comes to port number.

Well, suppose Node app is on port 8080, and my node application is available with the url www.nodeapp.com. I created an A record in the DNS to point the domain nodeapp.com to the ip address of my server.

The problem is that now I have to use the url http://www.nodeapp.com:8080 to access to my node application.

Is there a way to configure virtual host on apache2 to make it use port 8080 automatically with the domainname nodeapp.com